# How to separate string into parts in PHP

Tags: php, string

Right Now I Have:

```
$path2 = $file_list1; 
$dir_handle2 = @opendir($path2) or die("Unable to open $path2"); 
while ($file2 = readdir($dir_handle2)) { 
if($file2 == "." || $file2 == ".." || $file2 == "index.php" ) 
continue; 
echo ''.$file2.'<br />'; 
} 
closedir($dir_handle2);
echo '<br />';
```

When $file2 is returned, the last 4 characters in the string will always end in a number plus the file extension .txt, like this:

```
file_name_here1.txt
some_other-file10.txt
```

So my question is, how can I separate $file2 so it returns the string in two parts, $file_name and $call_number like this?:

```
echo 'File: '.$file_name.' Call: '.call_number.'<br />';
```

Returns:

```
File: file_name_here Call: 1
File: some_other-file Call: 10
```

instead of this:

```
echo ''.$file2.'<br />';
```

Returns:

```
file_name_here1.txt
some_other-file10.txt
```

Thanks....

Comment: Can the filename contain digits as well? If yes, what do you do if the original filename ends with a digit (thus, cannot be distinguished from the "call number")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big advocate of Regex but I decided to go slightly different here. Check it out:

```
$file = 'file_name_here19.txt';
$file_parts = pathinfo($file);
$name = $file_parts['filename'];
$call = '';
$char = substr($name, strlen($name) - 1);
while(ord($char) >= 48 && ord($char) <= 57) {
    $call = $char . $call;
    $name = substr($name, 0, strlen($name) - 1);
    $char = substr($name, strlen($name) - 1);
}
echo 'Name: ' . $name . ' Call: ' . $call;
```

Comment: This seems to be my solution, however if the file name ends in a number, it will be added to $call, as mentioned. Therefore, suppose each file name ends in "file_name_1__123.txt, this_file_name_2__456.txt" where the ending is always "2 underscores,call#,.txt" How do I modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: Oh I see, what you'd want to do is just another substr() call after the while loop. Something like $name = substr($name, 0, strlen($name) -2); That's not tested so just make sure the -2 is the correct amount for chopping off the underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to use Regex to do this effectively

```
$filename = reset(explode(".", $file2))
preg_match("#(^[a-zA-Z\_\-]*)([\d]*)#", $filename, $matches);
$fullMatch = $matches[0];
$file = $matches[1];
$call = $matches[2];

echo "File: " . $file . " Call: " . $call;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions:

```
preg_match("/^(.+)(\d+)(\..+)$/", $file2, $matches);
$file_name = $matches[1];
$call_number = $matches[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`pathinfo()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to cut off file extension.
2. Use [`preg_match()` function](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to separate name from number.
   3.

   ```
   while (...) {
       ...

       $filename; // some_other-file10.txt
       $filename = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME); // some_other-file10
       preg_match('/^(?<name>.*?)(?<number>\d+)$/', $filename, $match);

       $match['name'];   // some_other-file
       $match['number']; // 10

       echo "File: {$match['name']} Call: {$match['number']}\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: `basename` only strips the suffix if you specify it. And what should `.*+` be in your expression? Did you mean `.*?` ?